# How to insert layerslide plugin on a page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've built a layer slider with the LayerSlider WP plugin and I can't figure out how to add it on a page. I understand that I might have to use the shortcode which I have but when I put it in the page breaks.
I'm new to wordpress and on the page that I'm editing, all I have is deTheme Builder.
[image]

I've tried inserting a row and a text editor snippet and inserting the shortcode which:
[layerslider id="2"] but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting the slider using the Drag & Drop Builder
You can place your sliders into pages and posts using the Drag & Drop Builder.
1. Click on the button or drag into the editor in order to insert it.
2. Click on the "edit" icon of the Layered Slider element and chose a slider from the one you've already created.
3. Save Element
4. Publish

**for more option refer these link https://support.vamtam.com/support/solutions/articles/200736-guide-to-layered-slider-wp**